# Infinite Scroll in Visual Composer wordpress

Tags: wordpress, infinite-scroll, visual-composer

I'm using visual composer by http://vc.wpbakery.com/ on my wordpress site.

Is it possible to have Infinite Scroll using post grid in Visual Composer?
Do I need additional plugin to do the job?
Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: You can use post grid style `lazy load` it actually is the same as infinite scroll